# Close word document before looping to another

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Macros takes text from excel row, saves it to word document, saves word document and then loops to another excel row. I am not able to change macros so that it closes word document after it is saved, before looping to another excel row. Can anyone please help me? Here is my macros:

```
Sub ReplaceText()

Dim wApp As Word.Application

Dim wdoc As Word.Document

Dim custN, path As String

Dim r As Long

r = 2

Do While Sheet1.Cells(r, 1) <> ""

Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

 

wApp.Visible = True

 

Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="G:\Shared\macros\final.dotx", ReadOnly:=True)

With wdoc

.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<ID>>"

.Application.Selection.Find.Execute

.Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value

.Application.Selection.EndOf


.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<date>>"

.Application.Selection.Find.Execute

.Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 3).Value

.Application.Selection.EndOf
  

custN = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value & " " & Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value

path = "G:\Shared\til arkiv\final settlement forms\"

.SaveAs2 Filename:=path & custN, _

FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False

End With

r = r + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

Tried

```
.Close
```

But it leaves blank Word documents

Comment: The `.Close` method closes the workbook, but doesn't quit the Word application.  To close the Word application, use `wApp.Quit`.

Comment: By the way, you only need to create an instance of the Word application once.  So I would suggest moving `Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")` before the `Do While/Loop`.

Comment: `Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="G:\Shared\macros\final.dotx", ReadOnly:=True)` is incorrect. You do not open a Word template to create a document. You should use the Add method instead, i.e. `Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:="G:\Shared\macros\final.dotx")`

Answer (score 0):

- Create Word object with `CreateObject` before `Do` loop clause. It saves time to handle all docs with a Word app.
- Word app may create a blank doc, adding code to close it.
- `wApp.Quit` close the Word app at the end.

```vb
Sub ReplaceText()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdoc As Word.Document
    Dim custN, path As String
    Dim r As Long
    r = 2
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")  '**
    For Each wdoc In wApp.Documents
        wdoc.Close False
    Next
    wApp.Visible = True  '**
    Do While Sheet1.Cells(r, 1) <> ""
        Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="G:\Shared\macros\final.dotx", ReadOnly:=True)
        With wApp.Selection
            .Find.Text = "<<ID>>"
            .Find.Execute
            .Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value
            .EndOf
            .Find.Text = "<<date>>"
            .Find.Execute
            .Text = Sheet1.Cells(r, 3).Value
            .EndOf
        End With
        custN = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value & " " & Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value
        path = "G:\Shared\til arkiv\final settlement forms\"
        With wdoc
            .SaveAs2 Filename:=path & custN, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
            .Close False   '**
        End With
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    wApp.Quit   '**
    Set wApp = Nothing   '**
End Sub
```